# Converting string to raw string for json processing [Python]

Tags: python, json, string

I have the following code snippet:

```
input = "You can check it out here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay1gCPAUnxo&t=83s I'll send $20 in bitclout to the first 50 people that follow instructions at end of the video. This is revolutionary. Let's hope it works! <3Building it. What's up y'all"

def createJsonText(input):
    input = r'{}'.format(input)
    x = r'{ "text":"' + input + r'"}'
    print(x)
    # parse x as json
    y = json.loads(x)
    f = open("tone.json", "a")
    f.write(str(y))
    f.close()
```

When I execute the aforementioned code I get the following error:

> File "hashtag-analyzer.py", line X, in readJson
> createJsonText(input)   File "hashtag-analyzer.py", line Y, in createJsonText
> y = json.loads(x)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py",
> line 354, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
> line 339, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
> line 355, in raw_decode
> obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 4194 (char 4193)

How to resolve this?

Expected output is a json file with name, "tone.json" and the following data inside:

```
{
  "text": "You can check it out here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay1gCPAUnxo&t=83s I'll send $20 in bitclout to the first 50 people that follow instructions at end of the video. This is revolutionary. Let's hope it works! <3Building it. What's up y'all"
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you edit your question and put it there?

Comment: Don't use ```input``` as a variable, it is a function in python, this can cause some bugs.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have updated the question with output value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going the wrong direction here, if you want to create JSON.  You want `dumps`, not `loads`':

```
def createJsonText(txt):
    x = {'text': txt}
    y = json.dumps(x)
    open('tone.json','w').write(y)
```

Your code had mode='a' for append, but a set of separate JSON lines is NOT a valid JSON file.  If you want it to be a valid JSON file, you need the whole file to be one document.

**Update**

Alternatively:

```
def createJsonText(txt):
    json.dump({'text':txt}, open('tone.json','w'))
```